# Merging two rows within a dataframe - start and end time

Tags: r, dataset, data-transform

I hope I am doing this right, as it is my first time posting here! I currently have a dataset that looks like this (in total there are 160k entries):

| Geocode | Barrier.ID | Device.ID | City | Date | Time | State.code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 10:39:10 | Deactivated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 10:54:18 | Deactivated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:10:38 | Activated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:11:37 | Deactivated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:12:18 | Activated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:13:37 | Deactivated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:17:38 | Activated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:19:37 | Deactivated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:26:25 | Activated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:29:37 | Deactivated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:40:38 | Activated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:45:38 | Activated |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:49:38 | Deactivated |

Raw data input:

```
structure(list(Geocode = c("603", "603", "603", "603", "603", "603", "603", "603", "603", "603", "603", "603", "603"), 
Barrier.ID = c("7",  "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7"), 
Device.ID = c("392","392", "392", "392", "392","392", "392", "392", "392", "392", "392","392", "392"), 
City = c("Por", "Por", "Por", "Por", "Por", "Por", "Por", "Por", "Por", "Por", "Por", "Por", "Por"),
Date = c("31/01/2021", "31/01/2021", "31/01/2021", "31/01/2021", "31/01/2021", "31/01/2021", "31/01/2021", "31/01/2021", "31/01/2021", "31/01/2021", "31/01/2021", "31/01/2021", "31/01/2021"), 
Time = c("10:39:10", "10:54:18", "11:10:38", "11:11:37", "11:12:18", "11:13:37", 
"11:17:38", "11:19:37", "11:26:25", "11:29:37", "11:40:38", "11:45:38", "11:49:38"), 
State.code = c("Deactivated", "Deactivated", "Activated", "Deactivated", 
"Activated", "Deactivated", "Activated", "Deactivated", "Activated", 
"Deactivated", "Activated", "Activated", "Deactivated")), 
row.names = c(NA, 13L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to create something like the table below. Note that the first two rows of the first table have been removed, as an event must always start with an "activated" state code. Row 11 of the table above has also been removed, as there was an event there that was incomplete. There is only an "Activated" event, but not a "deactivated" event.

| Geocode | Barrier.ID | Device.ID | City | Date | State.code | Activated | Deactivated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | Activated | 11:10:38 | 11:11:37 |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | Activated | 11:12:18 | 11:13:37 |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | Activated | 11:17:38 | 11:19:37 |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | Activated | 11:26:25 | 11:29:37 |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | Activated | 11:45:38 | 11:49:38 |

Based on the value found in state.code, the time is either the "activated" or "deactivated" time. I managed to split the times by using:

```
df$Activated <- ifelse(df$State.code == "Activated", df$Time, NA)
df$Deactivated <- ifelse(df$State.code == "Deactivated", df$Time, NA)
```

Which gave me:

| Geocode | Barrier.ID | Device.ID | City | Date | Time | State.code | Activated | Deactivated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 10:39:10 | Deactivated |  | 10:39:10 |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 10:54:18 | Deactivated |  | 10:54:18 |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:10:38 | Activated | 11:10:38 |  |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:11:37 | Deactivated |  | 11:11:37 |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:12:18 | Activated | 11:12:18 |  |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:13:37 | Deactivated |  | 11:13:37 |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:17:38 | Activated | 11:17:38 |  |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:19:37 | Deactivated |  | 11:19:37 |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:26:25 | Activated | 11:26:25 |  |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:29:37 | Deactivated |  | 11:29:37 |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:40:38 | Activated | 11:40:38 |  |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:45:38 | Activated | 11:45:38 |  |
| 603 | 7 | 392 | Por | 31/01/2021 | 11:49:38 | Deactivated |  | 11:49:38 |

Then I got stuck, however, and I did not know how to proceed. My questions would therefore be:

1. How do I merge these rows together so that they show the "Activated" and "Deactivated" times on one row within a data frame (as shown in the second table)?
2. How do I exclude the events that are "incomplete" (cases where certain events are missing a corresponding "Activated" or "Deactivated" time)?

I thought about using cbind to combine these two rows, but due to the incomplete events (i.e. missing a "Deactivated" event for an "Activated" event), this would not work, right?

If anyone would be able to help me further, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: You can accomplish this easily with `tidyr::pivot_wider`. But what uniquely identifies the matched pair of rows to merge? Is it just that they are sequential? Or is it a combination of other columns?

Comment: Only based on if they are sequential indeed; the rest of the columns are all the same (unless we move to a new barrier - that will differ in everything). I will go and check pivot_wider now - thanks!

Comment: You might need to first create a column that identifies the pairs and then `group_by(pair_id_col)`, do the pivot and finally do `tidyr::drop_na` to remove the ones that are missing the deactivated time

Comment: Thanks! Would you have any suggestions on how to perform the paring? Would this need to be an if statement, due to the possibility of there being an incomplete event (i.e., if "activates" or "deactivates" appear twice after each other, remove row)? Or can this be done in an easier way?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you share a small reproducible example (copy-pasteable version) of your data. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I have now added the raw input as a list! :)

Comment: We might need a few more rows that demonstrate all the various of quirks in your data. E.g. do you ever get just deactivated or does the pair always start with activated?

Comment: Hey there - no problem! I have just added the really exceptional cases that might occur within the data (and updated the output). In table 1, the errors can be best spotted. An event always starts with an "Activated" event, so the first two rows would have to be removed. In row 11 and 12, "Activated" appears twice without a "deactivated" event, which means something has gone wrong and the entry on row 11 should be removed. I hope that clears it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work even with unarranged data.

Notes -

- I have joined date and time columns in order to check for events started on a calendar day earlier than it deactivated.
- I have assumed that if more than one activated state is in continuation, the last one will be counted only.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(Geocode, Barrier.ID, Device.ID, City) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
         code = State.code == "Activated") %>%
  select(-Time) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(code = cumsum(code)) %>%
  filter(code != 0) %>%
  group_by(Geocode, Barrier.ID, Device.ID, City, code) %>%
  filter(n() ==2) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Geocode, Barrier.ID, Device.ID, City, code), names_from = State.code, values_from = Date) %>%
  select(-code)

# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   Geocode, Barrier.ID, Device.ID, City, code [5]
   code Geocode Barrier.ID Device.ID City  Activated           Deactivated        
  <int> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>     <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1     1 603     7          392       Por   2021-01-31 11:10:38 2021-01-31 11:11:37
2     2 603     7          392       Por   2021-01-31 11:12:18 2021-01-31 11:13:37
3     3 603     7          392       Por   2021-01-31 11:17:38 2021-01-31 11:19:37
4     4 603     7          392       Por   2021-01-31 11:26:25 2021-01-31 11:29:37
5     6 603     7          392       Por   2021-01-31 11:45:38 2021-01-31 11:49:38
```

- If however, if you more than one deactivated states, the following strategy will work

```
library(data.table)
df %>% group_by(Geocode, Barrier.ID, Device.ID, City) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
         code = State.code == "Activated") %>%
  select(-Time) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(code = cumsum(code),
         code2 = rleid(State.code)) %>%
  filter(code != 0) %>%
  group_by(Geocode, Barrier.ID, Device.ID, City, code) %>%
  filter(n() != 1) %>%
  group_by(code2) %>% slice_tail() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Geocode, Barrier.ID, Device.ID, City, code), names_from = State.code, values_from = Date) %>%
  select(-code)

  Geocode Barrier.ID Device.ID City  Activated           Deactivated        
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>     <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 603     7          392       Por   2021-01-31 11:10:38 2021-01-31 11:11:37
2 603     7          392       Por   2021-01-31 11:13:37 2021-01-31 11:19:37
3 603     7          392       Por   2021-01-31 11:26:25 2021-01-31 11:29:37
4 603     7          392       Por   2021-01-31 11:45:38 2021-01-31 11:49:38

df
> df
   Geocode Barrier.ID Device.ID City       Date     Time  State.code
1      603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 10:39:10 Deactivated
2      603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 10:54:18 Deactivated
3      603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 11:10:38   Activated
4      603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 11:11:37 Deactivated
5      603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 11:12:18   Activated
6      603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 11:13:37   Activated
7      603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 11:17:38 Deactivated
8      603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 11:19:37 Deactivated
9      603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 11:26:25   Activated
10     603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 11:29:37 Deactivated
11     603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 11:40:38   Activated
12     603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 11:45:38   Activated
13     603          7       392  Por 31/01/2021 11:49:38 Deactivated
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The first code example seems to work beautifully!